# Service Fabric Error in Azure during deployment

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Having issues when deploying my cluster to Azure.
Everything works locally but when deploying to Azure I get an error when trying to call one of the services.

In Azure the service fabric is `6.1.480.9494`, and it cannot be upgraded.
But my local version is `6.2.262.9494` that was released 6 days ago.

Am I getting this error due to the different versions?

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricTestManagementClient4'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B96AA7D4-ACC0-4814-89DC-561B0CBB6028}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: Same problem here. Seems like they forgot to tell service fabric itself that there is a new version :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A failing QueryInterface call is usually because of using a newer SDK on top of older runtime. However, using 6.2 runtime locally, for .net you can keep referencing the corresponding NuGet pakages (3.0), they are compatible with the 6.1 runtime. We keep backward compatibility between SDK libraries and runtimes.

6.2 roll-out in Azure has been delayed due to a recall class bug: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/04/25/update-on-the-service-fabric-6-2-release-roll-out/

Answer (score 0):

To add some additional information for other people using FabricClient

I've seen two potential issues resulting in such a E_NOINTERFACE on one of the internal clients when you instantiate a FabricClient.

(1) Ensure that you have the Service Fabric runtime + SDK installed on the machine trying to instantiate the FabricClient. Normally this is your developer machine but if you are using FabricClient from some external machine (e.g. a Jenkins agent), then you will have to install the SF runtime + SDK there.

(2) The version of the SF runtime + SDK (and maybe whatever SF related DLL's you are linking in your project) are incompatible. Refer to the compatible runtime + SDK + nuget SF versions from the [Service Fabric release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/blob/master/release_notes/Service_Fabric_ReleaseNotes_91CU7.md)